# Using command button to automate a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am trying automate my excel workbook consists of 5 sheets . There is one summary page where I am including a command button which basically allows to upload a file and then fills up in specific sheets.
The error I am getting is instead of filling up the cells in specified sheets its filling up cells in the summary page i.e the page with the button. This is the code I have written so far.
      *The below is an example where I am trying to direct a file with extension **SIG** in sheet 3*

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fd
   .AllowMultiSelect = True
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "All files", "*.*"
.Filters.Add "ID Files", "*.ID", 1
.FilterIndex = 1
.Title = "Select SSI Identity File"
.InitialFileName = ""
  If .Show = -1 Then
  ReDim selectedPaths(.SelectedItems.Count)
    For I = 0 To .SelectedItems.Count - 1
        selectedPaths(I) = .SelectedItems(I + 1)
        Close #1

If Right$(selectedPaths(I), 3) = "SIG" Then
Sheets(3).Select
Open selectedPaths(I) For Input As #1

x = 4
        txt = Input(LOF(1), 1)

        With RegExp
       .Pattern = "\B/.*"
       .Global = True
       .IgnoreCase = False
        txt = .Replace(txt, "")
        End With


        With RegExp
       .Pattern = "S[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9]+"
       .Global = True
    Set matches = .Execute(txt)



For Each Match In matches
        Debug.Print Match.Value
        If x Mod 30 = 0 Then
                x = x + 4
         End If
                Cells(x, 1) = Match
               x = x + 1
               Cells(x, 1) = Match
        If x Mod 30 <> 0 Then
                x = x + 1
        End If
    Next





 End With

 End If
 Next

  End If
 End With
 End Sub
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, you select the sheet first and then fill the cells. That is not the safest way.

Try using the full reference to the cell.

Your section

```
    For Each Match In matches
        Debug.Print Match.Value
        If x Mod 30 = 0 Then
                x = x + 4
         End If
                Cells(x, 1) = Match
               x = x + 1
               Cells(x, 1) = Match
        If x Mod 30 <> 0 Then
                x = x + 1
        End If
    Next
```

should look like this:

```
    For Each Match In matches
        Debug.Print Match.Value
        If x Mod 30 = 0 Then
                x = x + 4
         End If
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(x, 1) = Match
               x = x + 1
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(x, 1) = Match
        If x Mod 30 <> 0 Then
                x = x + 1
        End If
    Next
```

I hope this helps, I think it really is that simple.